# Error with methods and while loop in java

Tags: java

I have problem with "compareMethod" and with the while loop, so if anyone has any idead how to help me i would be grateful thank you. I am using Eclipse as an Ide.

I want to enter three values and then to print the smallest one.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CompareValues
{
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println( "The smallest number is: " );
    int first;
    int second;
    int third;
    checkMethod( first, second, third );
}

static int checkMethod( int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int thirdNumber )
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
    System.out.println( "Enter three nubmers between 1 - 100: " );
    firstNumber = input.nextInt();
    secondNumber = input.nextInt();
    thirdNumber = input.nextInt();

    if ( ( 0 < firstNumber ) || secondNumber || ( thirdNumber > 100 ) )
    {
        System.out.println( "Invalid entry: enter numbers between 1 and 100 only: " );
    }
}

static int compareMethod( int first, int second, int third )
{
    if ( ( first < second ) && ( first < third ) )
    {
        return first;
    }
    else if ( ( second < first ) && ( second < third ) )
    {
        return second;
    }
    else
    {
        return third;
    }
}
}
```

When I compiled the code I got this message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The local variable first may not have been initialized The local variable second may not have been initialized The local variable third may not have been initialized at CompareValues.main(CompareValues.java:11)

Comment: What is the problem? Can you also indent the code properly please.

Comment: What's the problem that you have? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: The class does not even compile. You can't use || on an integer (secondNumber)

Comment: While loop? Where? .. what? Explain your problem please

Comment: @Kiril: you only get that message when you try to *run* code that doesn't even *compile*! When Eclipse shows you a red underline in your code, it means that something is broken **there**. Hover your mouse over that point and it will tell you more details. *Those* errors **must** be fixed, *before* you even try to run your code.

Comment: You can't completely change your code when you move past one error to the next.  Otherwise people's answers are no longer relevant.

Answer (score 1):

See the comments in the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;   
public class CompareValues {   
public static void main (String[] args)   {
     System.out.println();
     //print smallest number
     System.out.println("The smallest number is: " + Integer.toString(checkMethod(first, second, third)));
}   
static int checkMethod(int firstNumber, int secondNumber, int thirdNumber)   {
     Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter three nubmers between 1 - 100: ");
     firstNumber = input.nextInt();
     secondNumber = input.nextInt();
     thirdNumber = input.nextInt();

     //Correct validation of numbers
     if (0 < firstNumber || firstNumber > 100 || 
         0 < secondNumber ||  secondNumber > 100 ||
         0 < thirdNumber || thirdNumber > 100 )
     {
       System.out.println("Invalid entry: enter numbers between 1 and 100 only: ");
       System.exit(0);
     }     
     //return the smallest number here:
     return compareMethod(firstNumber,secondNumber,thirdNumber);
}   
static int compareMethod(int first, int second, int third)   {
     if (first < second && first < third)
     {
       return first;
     }
     else if (second < first && second < third)
     {
       return second;
     }
     else 
     {
       return third;
     }   
} 
}
```